# Navbar Scroll que cambie de color al pasar de sección

Tags: javascript, html5, bootstrap, css3, bootstrap-3

Estoy teniendo problemas con el menu navbar fixed que posee ciertos estilo en los lo botones y el logo, no se si lo estoy planteando bien, lo que quiero hacer es que al scrollear la pagina a una determinada altura el menu cambie los respectivos colores de los li y del logo. lo que he planteado es hacer dos menus en el html donde oculto uno y muestro el otro pero no se si esta bien planteado.

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation"> <!-- menu scroll fixed -->          
      <div id="header-container" class="container navbar-container">

        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo-building.svg" alt="logo de la empresa"></a>
          <!-- Colocar el IMG con el logo del sitio -->
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#Nosotros">Nosotros</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Proyectos">Proyectos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Edificios">Edificios</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Blog">Blog</a></li>            
            <li class="cblanco"><p class="navbar-text">+59 221 421 0847</p></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Facebook" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Twitter" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            <li class="cblanco"><a href="#" title="Youtube" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#Contacto" title="Contacto"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <nav class=" navscroll navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation"> <!-- menu scroll fixed -->          
      <div id="header-container" class="container navbar-container">

        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="images/logo-building.svg" alt="logo de la empresa"></a>
          <!-- Colocar el IMG con el logo del sitio -->
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#Nosotros">Nosotros</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Proyectos">Proyectos</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Edificios">Edificios</a></li>
            <li><a href="#Blog">Blog</a></li>            
            <li class="cblanco"><p class="navbar-text">+59 221 421 0847</p></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Facebook" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="Twitter" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            <li class="cblanco"><a href="#" title="Youtube" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#Contacto" title="Contacto"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container -->
    </nav>        
</header>
```

a este segundo le agregue una clase navscroll, este menú va superpuesto a un slider carousel
el script que arme es el siguiente
        (function ($){
          $(document).ready(function(){

```
        $(".navscroll").hide();

        $('.dropbox').hide();

        $(function (){
            $(window).scroll(function(){

               if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100){
                $('.navscroll').fadeIn();
                $('.dropbox').fadeIn();
               } else{
                  $(".navscroll").fadeOut();
                  $(".dropbox").fadeOut()
               }
            });
        });

    });
    }(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 1):

Vas bien encaminado, pero lo más correcto es usar jQuery para añadirle clases CSS al navbar dependiendo de la posición del scroll. Adicionalmente podés setearle la propiedad **transition** al elemento para que el cambio entre un color y otro sea más suave.

Sería algo más o menos así:

```js
$(function (){
      $(window).scroll(function(){
         if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
          $('.navscroll').addClass("azul");
         } else {
          $(".navscroll").removeClass("azul");
         }
      });
  });
```

```html
.navscroll {
    background-color:purple;
    color:yellow;
    transition:background-color 500ms, color 500ms;
}

.navscroll.azul {
    background-color:blue;
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: gracias! y una consulta mas, como haria si quiero que el menu primero aparezca con un background transparente y un los enlaces en color y que cuando baje a cierta determinada altura ese menu cambie de color de fondo y de li se entiende?

Comment: como en este sitio http://www.luatix.org/fr/

Comment: background-color:transparent;